# I have 2 groups of identical-looking data, one mentions "levels" and the other does not. How do I change it so that both have "levels"?

Tags: r

I'm new to using R and I'm using some ready made code. Trying to produces a confusion matrix (with Caret) but my definitions are off.
How do I make it that data2 also include `levels` at the end? What are the names of each of these kinds of data?

```
data1

  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

 [50] 1  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

 [99] 1 1  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2

Levels: 1 2
```

```
data2

  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

 [50] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

 [99] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

Since they are essentialy the same, I just want to change the kind of data, I guess...

Comment: `levels(data2) <- c(1,2)`

Comment: `data2 <- factor(data2)`. The levels attribute is automatically set. As for the types of data, the one with `levels` is an object of class `"factor"`, R's implementation of categorical variables. The second can be `"numeric"` (C's double) or `"integer"`. Try `class(data2)` to see exactly what. Or `str(any_object)` to have more complete information on it.

Comment: take a look at some explanations on `r factors` https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_factors.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me was:

```
data2 = as.factor(data2)
```

Thanks for all others for answering